# What is the classpath for the embedded solr server in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, classpath, spring-data-solr

I try to use an embedded solr server in my spring boot application. My configuration is as following:

```
package ch.*.rest.config;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrOperations;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.EnableSolrRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories
public class SolrContext {

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        EmbeddedSolrServerFactory factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactory("classpath:com/acme/solr");
        return factory.getSolrClient();
    }
    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
    }
}
```

With gradle I include the following dependencies

```
compile('org.apache.solr:solr-core:5.5.4')
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-solr:2.1.4.RELEASE')
```

The execution of the application throws the following exception:

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/acme/solr] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not exist
> Buildiat org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.createCoreContainer(EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.initCoreContainer(EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.getCoreContainer(EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.getSolrClient(EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java:80)
    at ch.*.rest.config.SolrContext.solrClient(SolrContext.java:23)
    at ch.*.rest.config.SolrContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca87555f.CGLIB$solrClient$1(<generated>)
    at ch.*.rest.config.SolrContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca87555f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4c9fb49c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at ch.*.rest.config.SolrContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca87555f.solrClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at ch.*.rest.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:13)
```

Obviously the classpath com/acme/solr is not found. How do I find out what the actual class path is?

For the setup I followed http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/#solr.annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation :

```
public EmbeddedSolrServerFactory(String solrHome)
                      throws ParserConfigurationException,
                             IOException,
                             SAXException
```

**Parameters**:

solrHome - Any Path expression valid for use with ResourceUtils that points to the solr.solr.home directory

This means you should create a Solr Home ( and put the solr configurations in there)in the resource folder for gradle to pick it up.
Then you should pass that path to the embedded Solr factory.
Hope it helps